# Set focus on controls after validation error

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

In my winforms project,for a particular form i have nearly 10 controls for firstname,lastname,age,Occupation etc..(including textbox,dropdown list) and a SAVE button

I have created class representing data source for these controls and implemented validation method in the same class which takes of validation for each property and throws validation message.

Problem is raises when i want to set focus on a  control which throws validation error in UI.

How i can implement this.Passing a control back to class is bad practice.

Do i need to change the way i have implement validation at class level?

Any suggestion/links?

Comment: Note: passing controls isn't bad.  A control is an object just like every other object.  You aren't "forms" programming. You're simply programming, and your objects happen to have onscreen representation. What *is* bad practice is having objects messing around with things that aren't theirs to mess around with

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use the actual validation techniques provided by .NET:

[`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) [`Validated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx)

I also highly recommend adding an [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) and using it to indicate what the error is.  No example of this is given, but google is rife with good examples.

You can keep your validation classes and simply subscribe each control to the methods on the class.

For example (forgive the K&R, it's easier to write on S.O., also this may require some tweaks, i'm writing from memory):

```
public MyForm : Form {

    Validator validator;

    public MyForm() {
        validator = new Validator(/*Arguments here*/);
    }

    public override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        targetControl.Validating += (o,e) => {
            try {
                validator.Validate(e);
            }
            catch(YourException exc) {
                e.Cancel = true; //References the validating event args
                //Whatever else you want to do
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the code as mentioned by you..The issue is that for example lets say I want to validate control LastName textbox, the above code works only if focus goes on to lastname textbox(GotFocus) and on focuslost it validates if it null/empty..I am looking for the one if focus does not go to that control and user click on save button.. it should show the validation message and set focus on that control